# Does the event when two BH without polar jets merge, cause a short living polar jet on the newly formed BH?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, matter, relativistic-jets

Does the event when two BH without polar jets merge, cause a short living polar jet on the newly formed BH? As BH need infalling material to activate their polar bursts does the BH falling into another one as it brings the needed material provoke the polar jet?? (Thanks for answering...)

Comment: Do either of these BHs have material outside their event horizons?

Comment: @PM2Ring Not obligatory... The option of no accr. disc is even more interesting for me...

Comment: Intuitively no, but I also would like to see a competent answer +1